# Slow processing of pandas dataframe when accessed with `iloc`

Tags: python, arrays, function, for-loop

I have a little optimisation problem with my script and I was hoping to find some answers here.

My dataframe (called df) has the following structure :

| Place | Date_1 | Date_2 | ... | Date_9000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Place1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1.4 |
| Place2 | 13.3 | 9.4 | ... | 0 |
| .... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Place500 | 10.1 | 0.5 | ... | 1 |

I would like to count, per place, the durantion of each sequence of events that have rainfall values <= 1. I would obtain this output :

| Place | Event_Duration | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Placex | 14 | 1999-07-04 |
| Placex | 54 | 2002-09-04 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I made a `for` loop by calling index like so:

```
import pandas as pd
c=0
outdf=pd.DataFrame
for i in range (0,len(df)):
     for j in range (0, len(df.columns)):
          if df.iloc[i,j] <= 1:
               c = c+1
          else:
               outdf['Event_Duration']=c
               outdf['End_date']=df.columns[j]
               outdf['Place']=df[Place][i]
               c=0
```

However, I have a large dataframe (500r x 9000c) which took a long time for it to run. I could convert my dataframe to an array and work with the numpy function `apply_along_axis` but being new to this type of function as well as having never used matrices in python before I stumble upon a few difficulties. It is why I was wondering if anyone here would be so kind to help me understand how I could change my code by converting the loop to a more optimized version.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "I could convert my dataframe to an array and work with the numpy function `apply_along_axis`" this will certainly not speed up your code.

Comment: In any case, you *must* provide example input and expected output, i.e. a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show how the dataframe is being constructed and also give some indication as to the magnitude of placeindex and dateindex?

Comment: @AndyKnight Thanks for your answer, I just modified my example.

Comment: You still don't show how the dataframe is constructed or give any idea of the magnitude of the ranges. Perhaps you could show the code that precedes/wraps  your sample

Comment: @AndyKnight I'm sorry, i'm not sure to understand it well. My dataset that i used to work is the 1st one. I obtain the 2nd one with my for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-need-for-optimization-when-using-pandas-8ce23b83330c), `iloc` is very slow and you should use `iat` when access time is crucial.

Alternatively, you could enumerate the row corresponding to "place `i`" in the inner loop, using `for j,cc in enumerate(df.iloc[i])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my real loop (more complex than this one), it divided the duration by 2.

Comment: So it was `iloc` indeed, but maybe you still use suboptimal accessors in the inner loop, since a division by 2 is less than the gain reported in the page I've linked.

Comment: It was just a part of my problem. In fact, i detected that the slowness of my code is caused by the fact that I save my results in a dataframe. It begin with with 0.11s per iteration (place), after 50 iteration 10second... and 2 minutes for 150 etc...

Comment: Yes, dataframes are not meant for this sort of systematic usage. If your data is homogeneous and structured as a matrix, better use numpy.